# AJAX incorrectly GETs and POSTs multiple data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on a feature of my webapp that allows a user to add a place to a list. The current path is to open a modal which shows the user's lists and allows them to choose which list to add the data to.

The problem I have is two fold:

1. For some reason when the user click's a list it tries to send the data multiple times depending on how many lists there are (eg. if there are 2 lists it tries to send the data to the chosen list twice.) This is causing all sorts of headaches at my database.
2. The modal doesn't seem to reset or something meaning every time I reopen the modal 2 more lists are added meaning there are all these duplicates ([example](https://ibb.co/PxbsrXB)).

I have tried adding and removing event handlers etc. but I can't seem to debug the issue myself. Thank you in advance for any support you can offer.

Here is the JS function

```
const addToListModal = function(venueName) {
  $('#userlist-modal').modal('show');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/userlist/',
    data: {
      'username': userName
    },
    success: function(data) {
      data.forEach(item => {
        var listName = item.list_name;
        var listId = item.id;
        var listItem = $("#userListsModal").append(
          `<li class="userlistModal" id="${listName}" data-name="${listName}" data-pk="${listId}">
            ${listName}
          </li>`)

        $(listItem).on('click', function(e) {
          if (e.target && e.target.matches("li.userlistModal")) {
            var listname = e.target.getAttribute('data-name');
            var listId = e.target.getAttribute('data-pk');
            
            addVenueToList(listId, venueName);
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        })
      })
    }
  });
};
```

AJAX Post:

```
const addVenueToList = function(listId, venue) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/uservenue/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value,
      'user_list': listId,
      'venue': venue
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('User added: ' + data)
    },
  });
}
```

And here is the pertinent HTML

```
<div class="modal" id="userlist-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content rounded-0">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel"></h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div id="lists-column" class="mt-1 ml-2 mb-1 col-2" style="height: 367px;">
                    <ul id="userListsModal" class="list-group list-group-flush" style="width: 250px">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      {{ form.as_p }}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(listItem).on('click', function(e) { …
```

`listItem` is not what you think it is here.

You did

```
var listItem = $("#userListsModal").append(`<li class="userlistModal" …
```

before - but that does not return a reference to the newly appended item, it returns the jQuery object you started with (that is necessary, for *method chaining* to work).

So what you are doing here, is adding a click handler for `#userListsModal`. And since this happens in a loop over your list items, you are adding this same click handler *twice* (here in this situation), resp. as many times, as you have list items.

Your check

```
if (e.target && e.target.matches("li.userlistModal")) {
```

inside the callback function still works - because when you click on any of the list items, the event *bubbles up* the DOM tree. You are *handling* it when it reaches `#userListsModal`, but the event target is still the list item you clicked on.

You need to either add these event handlers to the individual new list items you just appended, or – probably better in a case like this – use *event delegation*, set up *one* handler for this, outside of the loop that creates the list items.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation. Extremely handy. So to execute the preferred option you pointed out, how would I go about attaching an event handler outside of the loop? Will this not cause an issue with the dynamically created elements?

Comment: No, this will not cause an issue, when you are actually using event delegation – because that means, you bind the event handler to an already existing ancestor element. https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ has details.

Comment: Thank you again for this response, it didn't spoon feed but with a bit of reading of your answer and the link you sent I fixed the issue. I also feel like I have learned a new concept I can apply generally.

Comment: Do you have any advice on Part 2 of the question? I am using the workaround suggested below but this is more of a bandaid than a cure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's `one()` method: [one](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

So, instead: `$(listItem).on('click', function(e) {...})`

Do this: `$(listItem).one('click', function(e) {...})`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the list (of lists) is not cleared every time you open the modal dialog. So every time the same items are appended and new 'click' event handlers are added. Try to call jQuery [empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) method before running AJAX '/api/userlist' (it will remove all event handlers as well)

```
const addToListModal = function(venueName) {
  $("#userListsModal").empty();
  $('#userlist-modal').modal('show');
  $.ajax({ 
  // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. This sort of works in that it stops multiple lists DISPLAYING in the modal but it doesn't stop multiple lists from being called, in my console.log I can still see the program is trying to add venues to multiple lists.